# Execute python solvers from another python script using flag variables

Tags: python, workflow, command-line-arguments, compiler-flags

I'm currently working on a python pipline where I need to call different solvers/scripts from a python code and execute them. Since there would be different kind of codes involved, I would like to call these solvers based on flag parameters and run them accordingly. Below is an example of what I intend to do:

So there are two or more python codes, typically with 100s of lines of code, but here I have taken a generic example

```
#script1.py
import numpy
        
def test1():
    print('This is script One')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test1()
```

```
#script2.py
import numpy
        
def test2():
    print('This is script two')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test2()
```

At the moment I execute them from another script `main.py` with

```
#main.py
import numpy
from script1 import *
from script2 import *
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    test1()
    test2()
```

This `main.py` executes both of them which I don't want. I would like to use flag variables and execute them whichever I need to. Can this be done using `argparse` command line parsing ? As there might be further flags in each `script.py` for it to run. That would be something I prefer as well.

Thanks

Comment: yes, you can use argparse, so when you call your main.py you could pass which scripts you want to run. eg: `python main.py test1 test2` then inside the main you can put conditionals to check the arguments or use `ast.literal_eval()` to directly call the scripts using the parameter value

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki but how do I define `argparse` ? inside the `if` statement ?

Comment: Here you have an example https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html  You use your main.py to parse the arguments, then you check for each arguments if it's "test1" or 'test2" and call the appropiate function

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki most examples are to do with math on the command line or meddle with formatting lines on the screen. what I need is.. if arg is A do test1, if B then do B etc. efficiently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
#main.py
import numpy
import sys
from script1 import test1
from script2 import test2
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    # sys.argv[0] is the executable so we skip it.
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]   
        if arg == "test1": 
            test1()
        elif arg == "test2": 
            test2()
```

Now you can execute your tests as

```
python main.py test1

python main.py test2

# or if you want to repeat a test several times or run multiple tests

# will execute test1, then test2 then test1 again
python main.py test1 test2 test1
```